# SQLite error "no such table"

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm getting this error:

2015-06-11 12:06:42.103 actividadFinaliOS1[25425:1798557] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'no such table: recordatorios''

and I'm pretty sure the table is created. Check my code:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordatorios.sqlite"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{

if (!_todoItems) {

    _todoItems = [NSMutableArray new];
}

_databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recordatorios" ofType:@"sqlite"];

if (sqlite3_open([_databasePath UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    _consulta = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM recordatorios"];

    const char *query = [_consulta UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt  *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            char *item = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s" , item];
            [_todoItems addObject:string];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }else
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }
    sqlite3_close(_database);
}else
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));

}
}
```

Comment: If the runtime tells you it's not there then I'm pretty sure it's right with that and the table is missing. Maybe you got the wrong sqlite open.

Comment: This is the way i gave the path:


_databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordatorios.sqlite"]];

and the way i open it:
sqlite3_open([_databasePath UTF8String], &_database)

Comment: this error is driving me crazy, I doble checked the table is created on the terminal.

Comment: You can try to `lsof -p` the process and see what is the database that is opened by the application (you have to leave remove `sqlite3_close` however).

Comment: You print "error inserting" at the SELECT (hmm) as well as at failing OPEN (hmmm hmmm).